# How do i get specific List<class> property to array

Tags: c#

I want to get property of list class. how do i get the value by not looping it ? because i want list become an array. because for now on the 2nd Case it's using index, is there a way to make it simple like 1st Case ?

Before, Iam creating a list which only contain 1 properties and it worked. further more i want to make it a little bit complex by using a class/model. but when i try using by class, it can't expect my expectation.

```
//Model
public class model
{
    private string mCounter;
    private string mName;
    private string mEmail;
    public model(string mCounter,string mName,string mEmail)
    {
        this.mCounter = mCounter;
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mEmail = mEmail;
    }

    public string get_Counter
    {
        get { return mCounter; }
    }
    public string get_Name
    {
        get { return mName; }
    }
    public string get_Email
    {
        get { return mEmail; }
    }

}

//Example Data
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("counter", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("e-mail", typeof(string));
   dt.Rows.Add("1", "David","David@gmail.com");
   dt.Rows.Add("2", "Ben","Ben@gmail.com");
   dt.Rows.Add("3", "Henry","Henry@gmail.com");

//case 1:Done (Worked well)
//   List<string> Listcounter = new List<string>();
//   for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
//   {
//     Listcounter.Add(dt.Rows[i]["counter"].ToString());
//   }
//   //Result
//   var result = string.Join("; ", Listcounter.ToArray());
//   MessageBox.Show("e.g: " + result);
///////

//Case:2
     /////List
     List<model> listModel = new List<model>();
     for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         string counter = dt.Rows[i]["counter"].ToString();
         string name = dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
         string email = dt.Rows[i]["e-mail"].ToString();
         listModel.Add(new model(counter,name,email));
     }
//Result
     var result = string.Join("; ", listModel[0].get_Name.ToString() + listModel[0].get_Email.ToString());
     MessageBox.Show("e.g: " + result);
///////
```

Expect result is: only show the name and email in a message Box

David - David@gmail.com; Ben - Ben@gmail.com; Henry - Henry@gmail.com

Comment: for example listModel.Select(x=>x.get_Name).ToArray() or string.Join(";",listModel.Select(x=>string.Format("{0} {1}",x.get_Name,x.get_Email)).ToArray())

Comment: iam sorry, i can't get it work, could try to store it in a var ? because the listModel doesn't have Select() method.

Comment: @orlandeuman, `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks. before i tried to learn linq but still didn't understand nor remember how to use it. (before i tackle this problem)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a method in the `Model` class which will return already formatted string. Then you can get rid of public getters if you not using them for something else.

```
 public class Model
 {
     private readonly string _counter;
     private readonly string _name;
     private readonly string _email;

     public Mode(string counter, string name, string email)
     {
         _counter = counter;
         _name = name;
         _email = email;
     }

     public string FormattedData()
     {
         return $"{_counter}. {_name} - {_email}";
     }
 }
```

You can build whole string by looping data only once with `.Select` extension method.

```
var models = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new Model(
        row.Field<string>("counter"), 
        row.Field<string>("name"), 
        row.Field<string>("e-mail")))
    .Select(model => model.FormattedData());

var result = String.Join(", ", models);     
Console.WriteLine(result);
// 1. David - David@gmail.com, 2. Ben - Ben@gmail.com, 3. Henry - Henry@gmail.com
```

As @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth correctly mentioned, you don't need convert your collection to the array, just pass enumerable to the `String.Join`, which will be enumerated only once.

If you override `ToString` method in `Model` class, your code can become much simpler, because generic overload of `String.Join` accepts collection of any type and call `.ToString()` on each item.

```
 public class Model
 {
     private readonly string _counter;
     private readonly string _name;
     private readonly string _email;

     public Mode(string counter, string name, string email)
     {
         _counter = counter;
         _name = name;
         _email = email;
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return $"{_counter}. {_name} - {_email}";
     }
 }

// Usage
var models = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new Model(
        row.Field<string>("counter"), 
        row.Field<string>("name"), 
        row.Field<string>("e-mail")));

var result = String.Join(", ", models);     
Console.WriteLine(result);
// 1. David - David@gmail.com, 2. Ben - Ben@gmail.com, 3. Henry - Henry@gmail.com
```

Comment: You could use string join to shorten this

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth, OP wants to loop collection only once, but `String.Join` will loop it second time. You can fit everything into `String.Join` but I think `Select` and `Aggregate` would be more readable.

Comment: String join accepts an enumerable so it loops only once. I use this extension method personally, `public static string JoinString(this IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string separator) => string.Join(separator, enumerable)` which you can chain like `.JoinString(", ")`

Comment: well, i didn't think about making a method. but if i build the method, i need to know what index should i access, so i don't think it will work... but for the 2nd method can it extract from the list instead of the datatable? because it's just a sample. in the other project i need to put some kind of validation... but i appreciate it.

Comment: @orlandeuman, you don't need an index. You are looping all rows.

Comment: I thought there was 2 method. sory i didn't see properly

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Model
{
    private string mCounter;
    private string mName;
    private string mEmail;

    public Model(string mCounter,string mName,string mEmail)
    {
        this.mCounter = mCounter;
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mEmail = mEmail;
    }

    public string MCounter
    {
        get { return mCounter; }
    }

    public string MName
    {
        get { return mName; }
    }

    public string MEmail
    {
        get { return mEmail; }
    }

    # This method will output the results you need for each Model object.
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MName + " <" + MEmail + ">";
    }

}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Model> listModel = new List<Model>();
        listModel.Add(new Model("Counter 1", "Name 1", "email1@example.com"));
        listModel.Add(new Model("Counter 2", "Name 2", "email2@example.com"));

        string combined = string.Join( "; ", listModel.Select(c=>c.ToString()).ToArray<string>());
        Console.WriteLine(combined);
    }
}
```

FYI, C# code conventions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions